# Tracking down Berklee College student recordings

Tags: jazz

My middle school band teacher, who introduced me to jazz, was a Berklee alumnus, and had an outstanding album which included a number of Quincy Jones pieces recorded and arranged by Berklee students (including himself).

I had a cassette dub of this that wore out long ago -- are any of the Berklee albums available anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Berlkee archives refer to a certain [*Jazz in the Classroom, A tribute to Quincy Jones*](https://archives.berklee.edu/jazz-classroom-volume-06-tribute-quincy-jones/19143).

It is confirmed by [discogs](https://www.discogs.com/Jazz-In-The-Classroom-A-Tribute-To-Quincy-Jones-Volume-6/release/3083217), released in 1961.

[image: berklee]